# JQuery function wont push nor add value to property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this piece of code. Problem is that PUSH wont add anything to the array WORDS or if I try assign value to property. Data in collection that it iterates trough isn't null I tested it and calling other functions from that place in code work for example alert etc.

Thanks for your help.

Here is my piece of code

```
        var uri = 'GetTickerData';
        var words = [];
        var string;
        $.getJSON(uri)
                .done(function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                        words.push('Some text');   //dont work
                        string = 'Another text';   // also dont work
           });
        });
```

Comment: Can you put it on `jsfiddle.net` with the URI so we can test it out

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: well i dont have problem with data that it returns , if i use for example        $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#data'));     it will show returned data properly everytime so thats not problem

Comment: @Mitre `getJSON` is asynchronous call. So you can access  your filled in `words` array only inside `done` callback.

Comment: @Mitre How do you know it doesnot work? Where are you checking whats inside `words` and `string`?

Comment: Well i got piece of code that displays what is inside of WORDS. I also got console log with that from collection and its ok. But i think Antyrat is right and i just cant manipulate with that array in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested this, you'll have to let me know if this works for you

```
function getReturnedData(callback) {

   var uri = 'GetTickerData';
   var string;

   $.getJSON(uri, function (data) {
        var words = [];
        $.each(data, function (i) {                
              words.push(data[i]);
        });                            
        callback(words);
  });
}

getReturnedData(function(returnValue) {
  console.log(returnValue);
});
```

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work. I can see the Data from that List in Console no problem but that PUSH dont work. Problem is it dont work even with this simple text like     words.push('Some text');    also you cant assign value there like   var data_string = 'Some other data'; that also dont work there

Comment: @Mitre are you sure your response contain correct Array? Can you show us response?

Comment: @Mitre Could you show me some further information, so that I can provided you with a better answer?

Comment: Console response is 4x Object that goes like this       ObjectCurrentSpeed: 0Date_end: nullDate_start: nullExt_id: nullMaxSpeed: 0Server: "pdcesb001"Severity: "Average"Source: nullStatus: "0"Title: "QPID sft.int.sft.queue depth (delayed)"    so its got correct data.

Comment: @Mitre can we can talk of a stackoverflow chat? and i've also just updated my answer to give you an idea of a callback function

Comment: OK that stuff withcallback function solved my problem thank you alot its working now

Comment: @Mitre If you've got any other JQuery questions, feel free to ask me :)